# What "along x-axis means in polar coordinates" and how to find the limit of $f(x,y)= \frac{3(x-y)^2}{9(x^2+xy+y^2)}$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: limits, polar-coordinates

Use polar coordinates to evaluate the limit of a function
$f(x,y)=\frac{3(x-y)^2}{9(x^2+xy+y^2)}$ along the $x$-axis.

I know that to transform it into polar coordinates I have to assume $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$. And along $x$-axis means $y=0$. But what does along the $x$-axis mean in polar coordinates? How to proceed for this problem?.

Comment: It means $\theta = 0$ or $\theta = \pi$. However you don't have to use polar coordinates to calculate the limit (I suppose at $(0, 0)$).

Comment: So sir I have to take r tends to 0 and $\theta$ is 0 or $\pi$ since there y is 0?. I know i don't have to use polar coordinates but it is asked in question.

Comment: Maybe the point goes to infinity in either direction on the $x$-axis?

Comment: where do you want to evaluate the limit?